Unable to log failed boots via journalctl
Ubuntu's currently failing to boot on my system (hybrid Nvidia graphics), I've already reported the bug here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/2071680
But, journalctl only captures logs from recovery mode boots, and not the normal failed boots, so it's not possible to debug the problem.
So is there workaround for diagnosing the issue?
I've already filed about the boot issue elsewhere:
Ubuntu 24.04 won't boot on Nvidia 500-series drivers
Boot fails on Nvidia hybrid graphics
